# Updating records on dynamically populated list

Tags: php, opencart

I'm working in OpenCart and have a list and a form .tpl that work together, the form creates new records and that info is displayed on the list. The list gives options for each record(edit,delete,archive) Im trying to get the Edit function to work. When edit is clicked for a particular row I want the form to be displayed with the inputs already filled out with the existing information. Which then can be updated by the user. Currently what happens is when edit is clicked it doesn't launch the form but instead edits the current record, but with zeroes and empty columns. Im not sure how to launch back into the form. and display that users information

Model:

```
public function editCampaign($campaign_id, $data) {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns SET campaign_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_name']) . "', campaign_giving_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_goal'] . "', campaign_giving_count_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_count_goal'] . "', campaign_owner = '" . $data['campaign_owner'] . "', date_beginning = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_beginning']) . "', date_ending = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_ending']) ."' WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");

    }
```

Controller:

```
public function edit() {
        $this->load->language('campaigns/campaign');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('campaigns/campaign');

        if (isset($this->request->post['editButton'])) {
              $campaign_id = $this->request->post['editButton'];
            $this->model_campaigns_campaign->editCampaign($campaign_id);

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');



            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('campaigns/campaign', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true));
        }

        $this->getForm();
    }
```

View:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-order">

          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table" id="campaign-table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $column_campaign_id; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $column_campaign; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $column_giving_goal; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $column_giving_count_goal; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $column_owner; ?></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php if ($orders) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
                <tr class="campaign-list">

                  <td><?php echo $order['campaign_id']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $order['campaign_name']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $order['campaign_giving_goal']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $order['campaign_giving_count_goal']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $order['campaign_owner']; ?></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="campaign-dropdown-btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><?php echo $text_campaign_dropdown;?><span class="caret"></span></button>
                      <ul class="campaign-list-more dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="campaign-dropdown-list"><button type="submit" id="campaign-del" name="editButton" value="<?php echo $order['campaign_id']; ?>" onclick="javascript:changeFormAction('<?php echo $edit; ?>');">
                            <?php echo $button_edit; ?>
                        </button></li>
                        <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">Archive</li>
                        <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">
                            <button type="submit" id="campaign-del" name="deleteButton" value="<?php echo $order['campaign_id']; ?>" onclick="javascript:changeFormAction('<?php echo $delete; ?>');">
                                <?php echo $button_delete; ?>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </td>

                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-center" colspan="8"><?php echo $text_no_results; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </form>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeFormAction(action) {
        var form = document.getElementById('form-order');
        form.action = action;
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the edit button of type `type="button"`, so no submit.
2. Then, when you click on it, it should activate an ajax request of
   type `POST` to the controller action `edit()`, passing the campaign
   id as request value.
3. `edit()` should be responsible only with the fetching of the
   corresponding record's details from the db and returning of the rendered `form.tpl` content (having the details passed to it).
4. The rendered form content will then be read by the ajax object
   (inside the `success` callback) and written to a form
   container (like `<div class="form-container"></div>`) somewhere
   before, inside, or after the `campaign-table` list. You can instead define a
   form container in each record and let the ajax fill the one with the
   form.tpl content, to which the posted campaign id belongs.
5. The form will have its own submit button named `updateButton`
   (having the campaign id in its `value` attribute), which will send
   the form fields' values - completed by the user - to a controller
   action named `update()`. Of course, the campaign id will be sent
   too.
6. The `update()` action will then read all the POST passed values and
   update the record in the database. In the end it should resend the
   campaigns list back, with or without the form - it's up to you, how
   you want to have it - to be redisplayed, and a corresponding "update
   success/failure" message.

Good luck!